# What's the meaning of the parameter code in PendingIntent.send()?

Tags: android

I have read the PendingIntent document:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html

The function `send` is defined as:

> **public void send(Context context, int code, Intent intent,
>               OnFinished onFinished, Handler handler, String requiredPermission)**
>
> code: "Result code to supply back to the PendingIntent's target."

What make me confused is the parameter `code`. When I should use it and how can I get it from the PendingIntent send target (activity/service/receiver) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the result code associated with `BroadCastReceivers`

See: [getResultCode()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#getResultCode())

Can also get the final result code with a [OnFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.OnFinished.html) listener that is sent using the version of send you referenced.

Comment: So the parameter code only use by Broadcast Intent?

Comment: Very thanks. I need to write a simple demo to test. Thanks again.